# Replacing values in column with values from different column if they are a certain value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df below as:

```
col_a | col_b
Day      Afternoon
Night    NaN
Day      Morning
Lunch    NaN
Day      Morning
Day      Early Morning
Day      Afternoon
Lunch    NaN
Night    NaN
```

I want to replace all values in **col_a** that are **"Day"** with the value they are in **col_b** but leave all other values as they are in **col_a**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
m=df.col_a=='Day'#boolean select
df.loc[m,'col_a']=df.loc[m,'col_b']#mask and replace
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [.where](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) method:

```
df = df.where(df != 'Day', df['col_b'], axis=0)
print(df)
```

From the documentation:

> ". . .Where cond is True, keep the original value. Where False, replace with corresponding value from other."

Output mini-example:

```
    col_a   col_b
0   Afternoon   Afternoon
1   Night   NaN
2   Morning Morning
3   Lunch   Early Morning
```